# Comparison by 'as'

Tags: possessives

If I have two questions and both of them can be solved by the same concept then if I want to say that '**the explanation of second sentence is same as first sentence**'.
Is it correct, can I say this?

Or should it be '**the explanation of second sentence is same as that of first sentence**'

Or '**explanation of second sentence is same as first sentence's**.

Which of these is/are correct? Please help me.

Comment: You need to say: **the** same as x.

Comment: No. There are errors in all of these.  Try "**The** explanation of **the** second sentence is **the** same as **the** first [sentence]".  The definite articles are not optional here, also you can omit the last word "sentence". No need to repeat it.  Also "sentence's" is not a plural in English. We NEVER use an apostrophe before a plural S.

Answer (score 0):

The "that of" is optional. It is implied to be there even when it is absent. This is called *ellipsis*, where one or more words that are required by the theoretical formal grammar are not said, yet it is still correct.

(The "three dot" symbol … is called ellipsis because it denotes where words are omitted, though not through grammatical ellipsis. It is used in quotations where part of the quotation is missing (usually because it is not relevant to the purpose for which the quotation is being used).)

Comparisons are an area where you get a lot of ellipsis. Depending on context, you might even just be able to say here "the explanation of the second sentence is the same", because the reader will know that you mean "as that of the first sentence". Even in that case, *that* is serving as a stand-in for "the explanation", so if you wanted you could be really unnecessarily verbose and say "as the explanation of the first sentence".

Just by the by, however, there is another error in the examples you give. You need a definite article before "first sentence" and "second sentence", as shown in the preceding paragraph. "Same" also requires the definite article.

As to "the explanation of the second sentence is the same as the first sentence's", I'm not sure if that's wrong *per se* - the genitive has the same semantics at least as "of". However, it seems messy and would not look good in a formal context.